# SQL: Return different SUM depending on CASE

Tags: sql-server, sum, case

I have two tables with a `Header/Detail` relationship and I am creating a view.
The calculation of one of the columns on the view (`OrderQty`) depends on the value of one of the columns on the heard table (`Status`).
So depending on the `Status` I want the `OrderQty` to be the sum of different field, this is what I have tried:

```sql
       (CASE
             WHEN so.Status = 10 THEN (SELECT SUM(sod.OrderQty - sod.BackOrderQty - sod.CancelQty) AS v
                                       FROM dbo.SalesOrderDetail sod
                                       WHERE sod.SalesOrderID = so.SalesOrderID
                                         AND sod.Status <> 99)
             WHEN so.Status = 20 THEN (SELECT SUM(sod.DespatchQty)
                                       FROM dbo.SalesOrderDetail sod
                                       WHERE sod.SalesOrderID = so.SalesOrderID
                                         AND sod.Status <> 99)
             WHEN so.Status = 30
               OR so.Status = 40 THEN (SELECT SUM(ISNULL(sod.PODQty, sod.DespatchQty))
                                       FROM dbo.SalesOrderDetail sod
                                       WHERE sod.SalesOrderID = so.SalesOrderID
                                         AND sod.Status <> 99)
             WHEN so.Status = 50
               OR so.Status = 60 THEN (SELECT SUM(sod.InvoiceQty)
                                       FROM dbo.SalesOrderDetail sod
                                       WHERE sod.SalesOrderID = so.SalesOrderID
                                         AND sod.Status <> 99)
        END) AS OrderQty;
```

The whole view is:

```sql
SELECT so.SalesOrderID,
       so.SalesOrderJobTypeID,
       so.CarrierCodeID,
       so.SalesOrderTransportStatusID,
       so.CollectionDateTime,
       so.CustomerReference,
       so.FileReference,
       so.RequiredDate,
       so.SpecialInstructions,
       so.DeliveryNotes,
       dbo.ufn_SO_DecodeSOHeaderStatus(so.Status) AS Status,
       so.TransportCost,
       so.TransportRevenue,
       so.CurrencyCode,
       customer.AccountCode,
       customer.CustomerName,
       customer.Address1,
       customer.Address2,
       customer.Address3,
       customer.Address4,
       customer.PostCode,
       (SELECT UserName
        FROM dbo.SecurityUser
        WHERE dbo.SecurityUser.UserID = so.CreatedByUserID) AS CreatedByUser,
       (SELECT WeekNumber
        FROM dbo.Calendars
        WHERE dbo.Calendars.Date = so.RequiredDate) AS WeekNumber,
       (MONTH(so.RequiredDate)) AS MonthNumber,
       (SELECT ShortCode
        FROM dbo.StoreCodes
        WHERE dbo.StoreCodes.StoreCodeID = so.StoreCodeID) AS StoreCode,
       ISNULL((SELECT PickedQty
               FROM dbo.SO_SOAllocatedContainersView
               WHERE dbo.SO_SOAllocatedContainersView.SalesOrderID = so.SalesOrderID),
              0) AS PickedQty,
       (CASE
             WHEN so.Status = 10 THEN (SELECT SUM(sod.OrderQty - sod.BackOrderQty - sod.CancelQty) AS v
                                       FROM dbo.SalesOrderDetail sod
                                       WHERE sod.SalesOrderID = so.SalesOrderID
                                         AND sod.Status <> 99)
             WHEN so.Status = 20 THEN (SELECT SUM(sod.DespatchQty)
                                       FROM dbo.SalesOrderDetail sod
                                       WHERE sod.SalesOrderID = so.SalesOrderID
                                         AND sod.Status <> 99)
             WHEN so.Status = 30
               OR so.Status = 40 THEN (SELECT SUM(ISNULL(sod.PODQty, sod.DespatchQty))
                                       FROM dbo.SalesOrderDetail sod
                                       WHERE sod.SalesOrderID = so.SalesOrderID
                                         AND sod.Status <> 99)
             WHEN so.Status = 50
               OR so.Status = 60 THEN (SELECT SUM(sod.InvoiceQty)
                                       FROM dbo.SalesOrderDetail sod
                                       WHERE sod.SalesOrderID = so.SalesOrderID
                                         AND sod.Status <> 99)
        END) AS OrderQty
FROM dbo.SalesOrderHeader so
     JOIN dbo.Customer customer ON so.CustomerID = customer.CustomerID;
```

This gives the error: `Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.`
Does anyone understand what I am trying to do and could provide a solution?

Comment: I would move your logic into an `outer apply()` and hit the table only once.

Comment: FYI [3+ part naming on Columns will be Deprecated](https://wp.larnu.uk/3-part-naming-on-columns-will-be-deprecated/) and should be avoided (you use it in some of your sub queries). You are far better off aliasing your objects in the `FROM` and using those to qualify your columns. This avoids the use of a feature that will be deprecated and possibly removed in a future version, and makes your code much more succinct and readable.

Comment: @stu I have never used an `outer apply` before, but I will look into it, thanks.

Comment: I suggest you change your approach completely. Rather than a giant complex view, create one that does your calculations at the header level - all of them regardless of header status. That will shorten the query you need for this view / purpose considerably and isolate that logic easier maintenance. You could probably index that view if needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously this is untestable however you should be able to take the following approach:

Join your SalesOrderDetail table once using the common criteria and sum the required columns, then use the results in a simpler case expression.

Using `appy()`

```
...
from dbo.SalesOrderHeader so
join dbo.Customer customer on so.CustomerID = customer.CustomerID
outer apply (
    select Sum(OrderQty) OrderQty, Sum(BackOrderQty) BackOrderQty ... etc
    from dbo.SalesOrderDetail sod
    where sod.SalesOrderID = so.SalesOrderID
    and sod.Status <> 99
)sod;
```

Then your case becomes

```
case 
  when so.status = 10 then sod.OrderQty - sod.BackOrderQty - sod.CancelQty 
  when so.status = 20 then sod.DespatchQty
  ... etc
end
```

Comment: I am getting the error `Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.`
What does this mean?  
UPDATE: It seems to be another part of my view `ISNULL((SELECT PickedQty FROM dbo.SO_SOAllocatedContainersView WHERE dbo.SO_SOAllocatedContainersView.SalesOrderID = so.SalesOrderID), 0) AS PickedQty,`

Comment: There's no subquery above so I have no context; there *are* other subqueries in your query, any one of which could potentially return more than one row; double click the error in SSMS and it will highlight the line.

Comment: Thanks it was my fault, I missed out the `SUM` in on of my other sub-queries... I will do more reading up about `outer apply` so I can fully understand it